# Discern caveat literally

Tags: vocabulary

The meaning of caveat in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/caveat)
is "warning or proviso of specific stipulations, conditions, or limitations.""

In [Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/caveat)
"warning, hint of caution," 1550s, Latin, literally "let him beware," 3rd person singular present subjunctive of cavere "to beware, take heed, watch, guard against," from PIE root *keu- "to see, observe, perceive." Legal sense "public warning preventing some action" is from 1650s.

Mid 16th century: from Latin, literally ‘let a person beware’.

There's no literal similarity from its origin,how to understand literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely comes from the common legal phrase *caveat emptor*, which is Latin for "let the buyer beware", which in many countries is a formal doctrine, meaning that the buyer of a product or service is responsible for making sure what they are purchasing is of good quality before purchasing it - in other words, a **warning** that if they fail to do so, the fault lies with the buyer.

From there, it probably entered into common English, with "caveat" meaning "a warning similar to *caveat emptor*". This process of *generalization* of a term (moving from a specific meaning to a wider, more general meaning) is often encountered in the etymology (the origin of the meaning of words) of English words. It is this sense that gives the meaning of a "warning" or "public warning" described.

(For the record, increasing consumer protections mean that the **doctrine** of *caveat emptor* is becoming obsolete in many countries; the phrase, however, is still going strong)